# Problems with unsrt bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am writing  my thesis in LaTex but I have some problems with the bibliography.
As always, I use the unsrt bibliography style to get the citations in order of appearance. However, this time it doesn't work so as a first citation I have the number 2 instead of the number 1.

That's the code I use:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

The bibliography is in a .bib file. I also would like to add all the references I do not cite explicitly in the text. So I usually add \nocite command. It works but in the text I get [?] instead of citations.

This usually works in the past articles I wrote, I don't know why now it doesn't.
Do you have any suggestions?

(I am using Overleaf)

Thanks!

Comment: You presumably have an error in code you have not shown. You need to show something if you want anyone to say what is wrong with it.

Comment: usual reason for getting unexpected order is that you have a citation in a caption and so the first appearing citation is in the list of figures

Comment: Ah yes that's why! I completely forgot about the list of figures. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose that it has to be taken like this, isn't it?

Comment: you can use `\caption[shorter caption with no cite]{long caption with cite}` so there is no cite in the list of figures

Answer (score 1):

Tell `natbib` you want things numbered and sorted in the package options using `\usepackage[sort,numbers]{natbib}`, then tell it that's also how you want the references to be formatted `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` (ending in `nat` "suitable" for `natbib`). Then to toggle on/off the references use `\nocite{*}` and you will get something that looks like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\citet{alice} said something to \citet{bob}.
\nocite{*} % Toggle for unused references. 
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

where for the `references.bib` we have:

```latex
@misc{alice,
    title = {Something},
    year = {2020},
    author = {Alice}
}

@misc{bob,
    title = {Something else},
    year = {2020},
    author = {Bob}
}

@misc{charles,
    title = {Something completely different},
    year = {2020},
    author = {Charles}
}
```